# How do I exit a command prompt with Power Automate?

Tags: command-line-arguments, command-prompt, power-automate-desktop

I'm using Power Automate to open a specific file with VS Code. I'm doing this by running command prompt with the following command line arguments:

```
cd /d <file's folder directory>&&code <file name>&&exit /b"
```

This opens the file but an empty command prompt stays open, is there a way I could fix this?
If not, is there an alternative way to open a specific file with VS Code using Power Automate?

Comment: Bring the command prompt into view and type exit or, kill the process. Do the same in PAD as I’d you were clicking the buttons yourself.

Comment: how are you calling the command? PAD does give you the processID when calling a process, so you should be able to terminate it that way. OR there is a open and close CMD function.